# check if a textView picker view contains a certain string

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, uipickerview

I have an app that allows people to make posts. I am trying to check if my textView picker contains a certain text and if it does an alert should show telling them to pick again.

Image below

[image]

if the text contains "Job Category" I want an alert to show that says choose a category.

that field is a pickerView embedded in a textView. Here is how I set it up.

```
var data = ["Assembly", "Auto Care", "Electronic Help", "Item Delivery", "Handyman", "House Chores", "Junk Removal", "Lawn & Yard Care", "Moving", "Painting", "Pet Care", "Seasonal Work", "Other"]
var picker = UIPickerView()
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return data.count
}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    JobCategory.text = data[row]
}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return data[row]
}

let JobCategory: UITextField = {
    let e = UITextField()
    
    let attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Job Category", attributes:
        [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : GREEN_Theme])
    e.setLeftPaddingPoints(6)
    e.textColor = GREEN_Theme
    e.attributedPlaceholder = attributedPlaceholder
    e.setBottomBorder(backGroundColor: .white, borderColor: GREEN_Theme)
    
    
    return e
}()
```

and where I am trying to show the alert is here,

```
if self.JobCategory.text == "Job Category" {

          let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Hold up!",message:" Choose a job category. ", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)


          let continueButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Got it!", style: .default, handler: {(_ action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in

             })

          continueButton.setValue(GREEN_Theme, forKey: "titleTextColor")
          alert.addAction(continueButton)
          self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: on pickerview's didselect method check condition and on that show alert

Comment: should I evaluate the pickerView instead of the textView?

Comment: Yes. you should evaluate pickerview instead of textView

Comment: @RahulPhate Im sorry im still having troubles

Answer (score 0):

```
 func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    JobCategory.text = data[row]
    if self.JobCategory.text == "Job Category" {
        // write alert code here
    }
}
```